# How can I just open SMS inbox in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I want just to open SMS application inbox in Android when I click a button. Many answers are about reading the SMSs or writing a new SMS but I want only to access/open SMS inbox. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING);
startActivity(intent);
```